# How to get Har Object for the current tab in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension, I have created some basic extension. But I don't know how to get the har object from current tab.

I have viewed this github repo https://github.com/s3u/har-view.

Here they don't discuss about how to get har object from the opened tab. Thanks in advance.

As of now this is my code, without the har object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#har').HarView();
        var har = $('#har').data('HarView');
        har.render(data);
});
```

I have a manifest file which points to a html in which this js is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`chrome.devtools.network.getHAR`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) API to get the HAR file.